# Вывод меток по координатам из БД Oracle

Tags: oracle, yandex-maps-api, oracle-apex

Подскажите есть необходимость нанести на api yandex метки по более чем 30 000 адресам. Адреса с готовыми координатами будут браться из бд oracle. Подскажите как это осуществить: карту подключил, но как передать столько меток? Столбцы в БД Oracle: naimenovanie, nomer, adress, kod. и координаты: dolgota, shirota.

Comment: А как у вас вообще устроен обмен данными с БД? Данные из БД сами не придут.

Comment: Я создал карту в Apexe, теперь хочу скриптами или процедурами подгружать метки из бд.

Comment: Апекс? Это сильно меняет дело. Только с картами я в апексе не работал. Это же плагин, правильно?

Comment: Я бы сказал что это приложение (oracle application express).

Comment: Вам нужно связать данные из базы данных с менеджером объектов:

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/many-objects-docpage/
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager

Comment: Я правильно понимаю - вы хотите из javascript на странице обращаться к БД?

Comment: Да, но я не знаю как это делать.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ подойдет для APEX начиная с 5-й версии. Если у вас 4-я, то там сложнее, но тоже решаемо (хотя откуда у вас такая древность?). В 5-й версии в JS API APEX  появилась функция [apex.server.process](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/javascript_api.htm#AEAPI29523), она-то вам и нужна.

1. Запрос к серверу - Dynamic Action с типом `Execute JavaScript Code`, пример кода:

   ```
   apex.server.process ( "my_proc", {
        x01: "test",
        pageItems: "#P1_DEPTNO,#P1_EMPNO"
       }, {success: function( pData ) {
           // Здесь код обработки ответа от сервера
           }
     } );
   ```

Здесь вы передаете в функцию `apex.server.process` три параметра:

- название серверного процесса (об этом далее)
- объект с данными запроса (в примере - это `{x01:"test",pageItems:"#P1_DEPTNO,#P1_EMPNO"}`)
- объект с callback функцией - это та функция, которая выполнится, когда (и если ;) ) придет ответ.

Что можно передать в объект запроса: параметры вида `x01`, `x02`, ... `x10` со значениями, список итемов (см. строку с `pageItems` в примере) и много чего еще (подробнее в документации).
Что вы получите в callback функции: в нее APEX вам передаст JSON объект, который вы сформируете на сервере. Объект будет помещен в переменную `pData`.

2. Серверная часть - ответ на запрос. Это может быть `Application Process` (в `Shared Components`) или процесс типа `Ajax Callback` (на странице). Именно его название (оно регистрозависимое) вы передаете первым параметром в функцию `apex.server.process`. Делаете процесс типа `PL/SQL code`. Далее, собственно код:

   ```
   declare
     my_str1 varchar2(4000);
     my_str2 varchar2(4000);
     response varchar2(4000);

   begin
     // так вы получаете доступ к значению параметра x01 из JSON объекта в примере выше
     my_str1 := apex_application.g_x01;
     // Так вы можете получить значение итема P1_DEPTNO, который вы упомянули в запросе
     my_str2 := :P1_DEPTNO;

     // далее все как обычно - какой-то код по извлечению ваших данных и 
     // заворачивание их в JSON 
     response := '{[';
     for i in (select naimenovanie, nomer, adress, kod, dolgota, shirota
                 from my_table) loop
       response := response 
           || '{"naimenovanie":"' || i.naimenovanie || '",'
           || '{"nomer":"' || i.nomer || '",'
           || '"adress":"' || i.adress || '",'
           || '"kod":"' || i.kod || '",'
           || '"dolgota":"' || i.dolgota || '",'
           || '"shirota":"' || i.shirota || '"},';
     end loop;
     response := trim(response, ',') || ']}'; // получился массив объектов javascript

     // в htp.p вы передаете то, что нужно отправить на сервер:
     htp.p(response); // в response должен быть корректный JSON
   end;
   ```

То, что вы передали в `htp.p` на сервере, вы получите в `pData` на клиенте.

Comment: Отличный ответ. Но увы, от авторов низкокачественных вопросов оценки  не дождаться.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий :)

Comment: Подскажите, а через RESTful Services не проще будет?

Comment: @VitalySurkov Может и проще, но я их не пробовал никогда.